# Magento 2 - Get Original Price and Special Price of a Bundle Product

Tags: magento2, pricing

I want to get the original price of a **Bundle product** (Minimal/Maximal one). 
This needs to replicate what Magento is grabbing for the **WAS** price below so I can add a percentage off to product pages.

[image: Offer / Bundlke Price]

I can get the **Special Price** like below:

```
$bundleObj=$product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price');
echo $bundleObj->getMinimalPrice();// For min price
echo $bundleObj->getMaximalPrice(); // for max price
```

I've tried using the below but this just returns 0:

```
$_product->getPrice();
```

This also only has both with and without tax and the standalone tax:

```
print_r($_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getMinimalPrice());
```

Have also looked at:

```
$_product->getPriceModel()->getTotalPrices($_product,'min',1)
```

This seems to just be pulling similar data cannot get the original price.

Comment: you want to get price of assigned children products?

Comment: I guess so, whatever Magento is doing for the WAS price pictured above?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After studying a lot of files containing the `old-price` tag similar to that used in the markup for the **WAS** price, I found the below:

```
$finalPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');
echo priceModel->getAmount();
```

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

I figured it made sense to use `regular_price` instead of `final_price` and so used similar code in my block to get the **original price**:

```
$bundleRegularPrice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
```

So after playing a little bit I can confirm how to get the following prices:

### **Regular Minimal Price:**

```
$_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getMinimalPrice()->getValue();
```

### **Regular Maximal Price:**

```
$_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getMaximalPrice()->getValue();
```

### **Special Minimal Price**:

```
$_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getMinimalPrice()->getValue();
```

### **Special Maximal Price**:

```
$_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getMaximalPrice()->getValue();
```

These are all **including the tax** to get the value **excluding tax** change `getValue()` to `getBaseAmount();`.

**e.g:**

```
$_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getMinimalPrice()->getBaseAmount();
```

Answer (score 1):

if tax enable

```
list($minimalPrice, $maximalPrice) = $item->getPriceModel()->getTotalPrices($item, null, true, false);
```

if tax is not there

```
list($minimalPrice, $maximalPrice) = $item->getPriceModel()->getTotalPrices($item, null, false, false);
```

You will get the Minimum price as $minimalPrice and the Maximum price as $maximalPrice.Please let me know if you still face the issue.

Comment: Tried  this one unfoortunately this allowed me to get every price under the sun but the regular price. I think i've found a solution now however.

Comment: Did that solution work for you? Can you please explain?

Comment: No sorry, this  was something i tried originally but would just return the special prices. Special prices with and without tax / minimal maximal version from everything i tried.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Can you please share the function that you used for getting prices?

Comment: Yeah will do just checking it as at moment returning the object and just want the number.

Comment: Just added an answer for how i solved it. I couldn't figure out anything more about tax or not or minimal maximal tho but all i wanted was the minimal which was perfect and then used the corresponding tax for special price to work out the percentage. Thanks for your help tho much appreciated.