# product package with 2 prices, "from" "to", how to solve?

Tags: magento2

The bundle products page has 2 prices, minimum and maximum, but I need only 1 price, I looked in some forums but I couldn't solve it, has anyone had this problem? I need to solve this today, I need to deliver a project and all that is missing

[image]

Comment: Which one price you want to show?

Answer (score 0):

Try your in your custom code:-

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(YOUR_ID);
$bundleObj=$product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price');
echo $bundleObj->getMinimalPrice();// For min price
echo $bundleObj->getMaximalPrice(); // for max price
```

More information check this link :-

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/209639/85907**

**`THANKS.`**